# How to install binance-api-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to install binance-api-node. The source repository](https://github.com/Ashlar/binance-api-node), mentioned that I can install it by using `yarn add binance-api-node`. I have been trying but it says

```
"'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

Any suggestions?  Please,is there a way to know if the node js package is safe to use?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: have you installed yarn?

Comment: No, I have npm? Can I run through that? I didn’t know what yarn just now. Do you have any idea how to make sure is the package is safe to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't installed yarn you can't run this command so you can [install the same package through npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance-api-node) or you could [install yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) and then run this command.